# Stop Javascript execution while processing xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where if browser window is closed then i need to make an XmlHttpRequest and show the result in a pop before the window is closed. But in my current code the browser doesn't wait for XmlHttpRequest to complete as it is asynchronous and closes the window. how can i open a pop before the browser closes itself.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
window.onbeforeunload = sendRequest();
//method to send the request to server
function sendRequest(){
   xhr.open('GET', "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java", true);
   xhr.send();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
   }

//method to process the output
function processRequest(e) {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
 var xmlDoc = xhr.responseText; 
 alert(xmlDoc);
}
}
```

the result(alert) should be visible before window is closed.

Comment: you can try with async false `xhr.open('GET', "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java", false);`

Comment: not working for chrome, getting an error that false is  depricated.

Comment: A deprecation notice is not an error. It should still work, however this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you absolutely sure you need to do this? It's just horrible user experience.

Comment: Also your code is wrong You want `window.onbeforeunload = sendRequest;` assuming it would work

Comment: Also ALWAYS define the callback BEFORE the call: `xhr.open('GET', "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
   xhr.send();
   
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You can make change little bit in your JS codes:

Referred from documentation link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Example

where we need to cancel the event as stated by the browser, events like refreshing/ reloading a page or going to back page.

```
        function sendRequest(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = '';
            var __type= event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type;
            // __type === 1 || __type === 0 : comes when Browser refresh button is clicked...
            // __type === 2 : Browser back button is clicked
            if(__type === 1 || __type === 0 || __type ==2){
                // write here your AJAX request code or you can create a function for AJAX request & call up that function
                xhr.open('GET', "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java", true);
                xhr.send();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
            }
        }

        //method to process the output
        function processRequest(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var xmlDoc = xhr.responseText; 
                alert(xmlDoc);
            }
            // here you can write a code to close the browser window
        }
```